# Filtering products based on an array of selected items - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of products being listed on a page like:

```
{products.map((product, i) => {
  return (
    <p>{product.name}</p>
  )
})}
```

I have an component on the page that has checkboxes for each product category. I am trying to make it so that the product list will be filtered by whatever checkboxes are selected, it could be one selection or several.

So far, i have this whole bit of code:

```
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(state.source.api + "/cocart/v1/products")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setProducts(data);
      });
  }, []);

  // Adds each item selected into an array of "selected" items
  const newArr = state.theme.filters.categories.flatMap(category => category.data).filter(item => item.checked);

  const [filteredProducts, setfilteredProducts] = useState(null);

  var A = products.filter(e => e.categories.find(category => category.slug === "for-kids"));
  var B = products.filter(e => e.categories.find(category => category.slug === "for-me") && e.categories.find(category => category.slug === "soft"));

  function showA() {
    setfilteredProducts(A)
  }
  function showB() {
    setfilteredProducts(B)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => showA()}>For Kids</button>
      <button onClick={() => showB()}>Me & Soft</button>

      {filteredProducts && filteredProducts.map((item, id) => {
        return (
          <p>{item.name}</p>
        )
      }}
    </>
  )
```

The newArr returns the selected items like this:

[image]

Right now, the buttons are just there for initial testing. Ultimately, the checkboxes, which are in a popup modal, once any checkbox is selected, the products will automatically update based on the selected boxes. For right now, the second button is just a visual to click on. If i can make that button show the results, then I can go from there.

My problem is, I am trying to have function `showB` set up so that it will filter based on the items that are in newArr - the selected checkboxes. But I have not been able to figure out how to write `showB` function so that it will filter by the items in newArr.

Any help would really be appreciated!

Update:

`products` returns the following:

```
{
  "id": 23901,
  "name": "5000 Close Out",
  "price": "$219.00",
  "on_sale": true,
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": 217,
      "name": "For Guest Rooms",
      "slug": "for-guest-rooms"
    },
    {
      "id": 216,
      "name": "For Kids",
      "slug": "for-kids"
    },
    {
      "id": 221,
      "name": "Medium-Firm",
      "slug": "medium-firm"
    },
    {
      "id": 224,
      "name": "Pocketed Coil",
      "slug": "pocketed-coil"
    }
  ],
}
```

Comment: In other words, you need your buttons to work as checkboxes?

Comment: @raina77ow not quite, i will update the question to address that

Comment: @raina77ow updated.

Comment: `setfilteredPolls` what does this function do ?

Comment: @Harkal that was a typo, i updated

Comment: in template dont use the `products` variable instead create another variable `filteredProducts` whose default value ll be equal to `products` and on button click you could just set the value of `filteredProducts` based on the category seleccted but the user

Comment: @Harkal do you have a code example? I already have a variable ```filteredProducts```. What I am needing is a way for function ```showB``` to filter by selected checkboxes.

Comment: @bk___ ll you post the class `Product` so that i know the fields in it

Comment: @Harkal i've added it

Comment: please add it in code @bk___

Comment: @Harkal i updated it

Comment: @bk___ wait i m updating my answer

Answer (score 0):

As I can see this is how the `Product` class looks like

```
class Category {
   ...
   slug?: string;
   ...
}
class Prodcut {
 categories?: Category[];
}
```

This is a pseudo implementation of a component

```
...
products?: Product[]; // you set the value of this from api call
filteredProducts?: Product[] = []; // the filtered products based on the selected category. you should use this variable in your template to render the produts and as when you get the products, set the value of filteredProducts = products
filters: string[] = []; // all the selected filters

filterB(): void {
    filteredProducts = this.products.filter(product => {
        var allow = false;
        for(const temp of product.categories){
            if(!allow){
               allow = this.filters.includes(temp.slug)
            }
        }
        return allow;
    });
}
...
```

The `filterB` function sets the value of `filteredProducts` as when you call it